# Passing in an function to solve integral equation with fsolve

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve an integral equation of the form

```
              Integrate[f(x)*g(x,w),dx]
Solve for w:  ------------------------  =  0.5
                 Integrate[f(x),dx]
```

of which there are definite limits (numerical integration).

Searching around on this and mathworks website I found some code that does it using functions in functions. I have run into a few problems though:

The code currently is (simplified equations for testing):

```
function [bfound]=testingSolveIntegral

options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',50);
bfound = fsolve(@func2minimize,[1 2 3],options); %testing start points at 1,2,3

  function output = func2minimize(w)
      t0 = -1;
      t1 = 1;
      L = 0.5;
      output = (L - (integral(@myFunc,t0,t1,'ArrayValued',true,'RelTol',1e-30,'AbsTol',1e-30)./integral(@myFunc2,t0,t1,'ArrayValued',true,'RelTol',1e-30,'AbsTol',1e-30)));

      function f = myFunc(muu)
          f = B.*muu.^2*(w.*muu.^2);
      end

      function f2 = myFunc2(muu)
          f2 = B.*muu^2;
      end
  end
end
```

This works wonderfully, but what I would like to do is then solve these equations in a loop for different values of B, eg, B = 1:1:100. I have tried a few things inside this code but only get errors.

Do I need to call this function from an outside script which dictates the B loop?

I would also like to define my functions in this outside script eg something like:

```
func = @(muu) B.*muu.^2*(w.*muu.^2);
func2 = @(muu) B.*muu^2;
for B = 1:1:100
testingSolveIntegral(func,func2,B)
```

I have tried a few things but am getting lost in the torrent of functions flying around the place. Assistance on how to set up such a script would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Put the function definitions inside the `for`-loop for a start, otherwise the value of `B` wont update.

Comment: Thanks, that's one thing I forgot. The other problem is I don't know how to specify the functions outside that main function `testingSolveIntegral`. What I mean is something like `func = @(muu) B.*muu.^2*(w.*muu.^2); testingSolveIntegral(B,func)` with func being recieved as myFunc in `testingSolveIntegral`...

Comment: If you use `testingSolveIntegral(B,func)` to call the function, and if the function is defined as `function bfound=testingSolveIntegral(b,myFunc)` then the variables `B` and `func` will be called `b` and `myFunc` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, I am making sure the variable names are correct inside the function. The area I am stuck with is when I remove `function f = myFunc(muu);  f = B.*muu.^2*(w.*muu.^2); end` (from the original `functiontestingSolveIntegral`. And try to pass it in as `func = @(muu) B.*muu.^2*(w.*muu.^2);
testingSolveIntegral(B,func)` I am getting the error `Undefined function or variable 'w'`.

Comment: Note that the second integral (the one you divide by) does not depend on `w` and is thus constant; no need to re-compute that every time. As such, you'd do `output = L*I - integral(...)`, with `I` the value of the second integral you have computed outside.

Comment: IS it possible you post your *real* equations? Perhaps it's possible to simplify things a bit more...

Comment: Hi Rody, the division integral is constant yes, I just want to be able to loop over the `B` values. The real equation is just needlessly long, and I am after more an idea of how to solve these typs of problems. I am fine with the equations my issue is the correct MATLAB syntax to pass in a function so it behaves like it previously did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [integral](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/integral.html?s_tid=int_b_int) doc page tells you how to perfom this task (section "Integrate Parametrized Function").

First define functions `f` and `g` with as many arguments as you have parameters/variables. For example, define:

```
g = @(muu,w) muu.^2*(w.*muu.^2);
f = @(muu) muu.^2;
```

Then call `integral` with an anonymous function which fix the values of the parameters:

```
for w=1:100
    q(w) = integral(@(x) g(x,w).*f(x),bmin, bmax)./integral(f,bmin, bmax);
end
```

Comment: Hi, this particular syntax is not the one I am stuck on. It is changing the original script so I can pass in the two integrals as functions and loop for solving vales for each `B`. Because the original one are functions in functions. So essentially I want to take out the `function f = myFunc(muu)
          f = B.*muu.^2*(w.*muu.^2);
      end

      function f2 = myFunc2(muu)
          f2 = B.*muu^2;
      end`, and be able to pass them into `testingSolveIntegral` and looping over B.

Comment: @SteveHatcher You can keep the definition of local functions, but I advise you to change their prototype and add arguments for parameters `B` and `w`. Then you can define anonymous functions to fix the value of these parameters inside your loop.